# Review Tools Broken?

Tags: support, bug

https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last30days is completely empty.  Is there a problem??

Comment: Looks to be that way, I'll bring it up with the powers that be

Comment: never mind.  I was on the meta page, but meant to be on the main page

Comment: Actually I didn't catch that either, its because there have been no closes in the last 30 days here

Comment: Scott, you might want to self-answer this, then :)

Answer (score 1):

There have been no reviews in the last 30 days.

A better place is to check here:
https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history

The last close vote was April 20th 2020